# XSLT Confusion with xsl:apply-templates

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file with this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<OpacResult>
<valueObjects class="list">
    <Catalog>
        <notes>
            Daily newsletter available via e-mail.&#xd;
            IP authenticated. Login not needed within firm.
        </notes>
        <title>Health law360. </title>
        <url>http://health.law360.com/</url>
        <catalogTitles class="list">
            <CatalogTitle>
                <uuid>e5e2bc53ac1001f808cddc29f93ecad8</uuid>
                <timeChanged class="sql-timestamp">2010-12-14 09:17:10.707</timeChanged>
                <timeEntered class="sql-timestamp">2010-12-14 09:17:10.707</timeEntered>
                <whoChanged>B23DE2FFE8DD49B0B0A03D1FEB3E7DA2</whoChanged>
                <whoEntered>B23DE2FFE8DD49B0B0A03D1FEB3E7DA2</whoEntered>
                <updateSearchIndex>true</updateSearchIndex>
                <corpId>RopesGray</corpId>
                <catalogUuid>a20b6b4bac1001f86d28280ed0ebeb9e</catalogUuid>
                <type>O</type>
                <title>Law 360. Health law.</title>
            </CatalogTitle>
            <CatalogTitle>
                <uuid>e5e2bc53ac1001f808cddc299ddfe49d</uuid>
                <timeChanged class="sql-timestamp">2010-12-14 09:17:10.707</timeChanged>
                <timeEntered class="sql-timestamp">2010-12-14 09:17:10.707</timeEntered>
                <whoChanged>B23DE2FFE8DD49B0B0A03D1FEB3E7DA2</whoChanged>
                <whoEntered>B23DE2FFE8DD49B0B0A03D1FEB3E7DA2</whoEntered>
                <updateSearchIndex>true</updateSearchIndex>
                <corpId>RopesGray</corpId>
                <catalogUuid>a20b6b4bac1001f86d28280ed0ebeb9e</catalogUuid>
                <type>O</type>
                <title>Health law 360</title>
            </CatalogTitle>
            <CatalogTitle>
                <uuid>e5e2bc53ac1001f808cddc29ec1d959b</uuid>
                <timeChanged class="sql-timestamp">2010-12-14 09:17:10.707</timeChanged>
                <timeEntered class="sql-timestamp">2010-12-14 09:17:10.707</timeEntered>
                <whoChanged>B23DE2FFE8DD49B0B0A03D1FEB3E7DA2</whoChanged>
                <whoEntered>B23DE2FFE8DD49B0B0A03D1FEB3E7DA2</whoEntered>
                <updateSearchIndex>true</updateSearchIndex>
                <corpId>RopesGray</corpId>
                <catalogUuid>a20b6b4bac1001f86d28280ed0ebeb9e</catalogUuid>
                <type>O</type>
                <title>Health law three hundred sixty</title>
            </CatalogTitle>
        </catalogTitles>
        <catalogUrls class="list"/>
        <gmd>
            <uuid>f8f123acc0a816070192e296a6a71715</uuid>
            <timeChanged class="sql-timestamp">2006-10-10 15:23:37.813</timeChanged>
            <timeEntered class="sql-timestamp">2005-01-27 00:00:00.0</timeEntered>
            <whoChanged>25db9fcd3fd247f4a20485b40cc134ad</whoChanged>
            <whoEntered>user</whoEntered>
            <updateSearchIndex>true</updateSearchIndex>
            <corpId>RopesGray</corpId>
            <isRuleDefault>false</isRuleDefault>
            <ruleName>text</ruleName>
            <term>electronic resource</term>
            <preferCollection>false</preferCollection>
            <isTechnicalManual>false</isTechnicalManual>
            <sip2IsMagnetic>false</sip2IsMagnetic>
        </gmd>
        <issues class="list"/>
    </Catalog>
</valueObjects>
</OpacResult>
```

As you can see, there are other  elements under sibling nodes, but I don't care about these and only want to see the first one.

I'm using this code to call a template with the string of desired elements as the parameter
and a template to loop through the asterisk-delimited string parameter: (title*url*notes*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="columns" />
<xsl:template match="/OpacResult/valueObjects">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">

                <!-- Header row -->
                <tr>
                    <xsl:call-template name="print-headers">
                        <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </tr>

                <!-- Value rows -->
                <xsl:for-each select="Catalog">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:call-template name="print-values">
                            <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Split up string of column names and create header field names based on element names-->
<xsl:template name="print-headers">
    <xsl:param name="columns"/>

    <xsl:variable name="newList" select="$columns"/>
    <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newList, '*')" />
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newList, '*')" />

    <th>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Catalog/*[name()=$first]">
            <xsl:with-param name="header">true</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </th>

    <xsl:if test="$remaining">
        <xsl:call-template name="print-headers">
            <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$remaining"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="print-values">
    <xsl:param name="columns"/>

    <xsl:variable name="newList" select="$columns"/>
    <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newList, '*')" />
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newList, '*')" />

    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Catalog/*[name()=$first]"/>
    </td>

    <xsl:if test="$remaining">
        <xsl:call-template name="print-values">
            <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$remaining"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:param name="header"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$header='true'">
            <xsl:text>Title</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//*[name()='url']"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="//*[name()='title']"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="url">
    <xsl:param name="header"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$header='true'">
            <xsl:text>URL</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//*[name()='url']"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="//*[name()='url']"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="notes">
    <xsl:param name="header"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$header='true'">
            <xsl:text>Notes</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="//*[name()='notes']"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="holdingNotes">
    <xsl:param name="header"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$header='true'">
            <xsl:text>Holding Notes</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="//*[name()='holdingNotes']"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="relatedUrl">
    <xsl:param name="header"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$header='true'">
            <xsl:text>Related URL</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="//*[name()='relatedUrl']"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bibliographicType/hasDataFile">
    <xsl:param name="header"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$header='true'">
            <xsl:text>File</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="Catalog/*[name()='hasDataFile']"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The only way I can access this template is to use the //*[name()=$first] syntax to extract the value of the element based on the name from the $first parameter.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks very much in advance.  Not including the full XML as there are thousands of lines of unnecessary text.

Comment: 13 questions asked, only one answer accepted, only three votes ever given.  Yeah, I'm not going to waste my time on you.

Comment: No complete xml document or complete xslt code are provided. How do you expect that someone would be able even to repro your problem?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your desired output is.  Also, where do the url, notes elements fall in the XML?  Are they children of Catalog, catalogTitles, or catalogTitle?

Comment: Thanks for wasting your time on me anyway, Paul!  Not my fault if people don't resolve my questions.. I'm not gonna approve false answers to inflate peoples' egos.

Comment: url and notes are also child elements of the Catalog element.  They were only included to show what the input string looks like.

Comment: @Music-Magi: The problem is in the code you haven't provided. Please, provide a complete (but the minimal possible) code + XML document that demonstrate the problem. We need to run your complete )but as minimal as possible) transformation on your complete (but as minimal as possible) XML document, to see what result we get and then to correct your code.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre - I've added the full XML and XSLT

Comment: @Music-Magi: The XSLT code is not "full". There isn't `<xsl:stylesheet>` and I suspect that there might be other templates that are not shown.

Comment: There are two XSLT compilation errors: "Variable "columns" is not declared" -- something is definitely missing...

Comment: Try again please.  Everything should be there now

Comment: @Music-Magi: There is some progress (had to close the `<xsl:stylesheet>` manually), but the result I get is just a table with the header row cells populated but the second row `td`s are empty. And I don't see what you wnat the result to be, what is the result that you really get and what is your question?

Comment: The transformation should display the header rows and one row or data without repeating any of the information more than once.  It should look something like this:

Comment: <html>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Health law360. </td>
                <td>http://health.law360.com/</td>
                <td>             Daily newsletter available via e-mail.
             IP authenticated. Login not needed within firm.         </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>     My question is how to display the data correctly with only finding the first <title> element and not all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:h="header"
 exclude-result-prefixes="h">
    <h:h>
        <title>Title</title>
        <url>URL</url>
        <notes>Notes</notes>
    </h:h>
    <xsl:param name="pColumns" select="'title url notes'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/OpacResult/valueObjects">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                             select="document('')/*/h:h"
                             mode="filter"/>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Catalog">
        <tr>
            <xsl:call-template name="filter"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="h:h/*">
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </th>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Catalog/*">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="filter" name="filter">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(
                                          concat(' ',$pColumns,' '),
                                          concat(' ',name(),' '))]">
            <xsl:sort select="substring-before(
                                 concat(' ',$pColumns,' '),
                                 concat(' ',name(),' '))"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Health law360. </td>
                <td>http://health.law360.com/</td>
                <td>             Daily newsletter available via e-mail.
             IP authenticated. Login not needed within firm.         </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note**: Inline data for headers, pseudo sequence parameter for filtering and sorting, modes not for processing the same element in different way but for processing different elements in the same way also.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  I'm still learning XSLT, so I'm not familiar with all the tags you used here.  However, the goal of this application (I should've mentioned this earlier) was to avoid referencing the name of the columns anywhere and just be able to build the header row and fill in the data given only the names of the columns from the calling code.

Comment: @Music Magi: That's not clear from your question nor your stylesheet. For that, you could pass the elements names and use their capitalization form for headers, instead of my inline data aligned with your stylesheet intentions.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but I'm sure it's not the best way to do it.  Within the templates for each of my expected fields, I have added:

```
<xsl:if test=position()=1">
    .. process data here ..
</xsl:if>
```

Ideally, there would be a way to tell this to process only the first element it finds:

```
<th>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[name()=$first]">
        <xsl:with-param name="header">true</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</th>
```

Edit: As I suspected, this will not work when there is more than one Catalog element to parse.  So instead of grabbing the first element for each catalog parent element, it's grabbing the first element in the document every time

Comment: Your absolute expression `//*[name()='notes']` would select every element named "notes" in the whole document (not just in context `Catalog`'s child)